# Shared react-native library cannot be imported into a webpack-based React app

Tags: react-native, webpack

I have 2 apps in a mono-repo built with yarn workspaces + turborepo:

- a react-native + expo app
- chrome-extension (uses some React components)

Naturally I don't want to repeat myself, so I tried to extract a shared library with react-native components that would optimally be converted to web components that can then be used in the chrome-extension.

packages/react-commons files:

- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- src/...TS files

packages/react-commons/package.json

```
{
  "name": "@opin/react-commons",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
  "types": "./src/index.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "lint": "eslint \"**/*.ts*\""
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "firebase": "*",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tsconfig": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "expo-av": "~13.2.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0"
  }
}
```

apps/chrome-extension/package.json

```
{
  "name": "@opin/chrome-extension",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production --progress",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@opin/firestore": "*",
    "firebase": "^9.21.0",
    "flat": "^5.0.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.4",
    "uuid-by-string": "^4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yargs": "^17.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.4",
    "@opin/eslint-config-custom": "*",
    "@opin/tsconfig": "*",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/chrome": "^0.0.229",
    "@types/flat": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.30.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.11",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.80.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.2",
    "yargs": "^17.7.1"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

apps/chrome-extension/babel.config.json

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": 3
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

apps/chrome-extension/webpack.config.json

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (_, config) => {
  const alias =
    config.mode === 'development'
      ? {
          [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/background/background-client.ts')]: [
            path.resolve(
              __dirname,
              'src/background/embedded-background-client.ts'
            ),
          ],
        }
      : {};
  return {
    entry: {
      background: './src/background/background.ts',
      extension: './src/popup/index.tsx',
      demo: './src/popup/demo/index.tsx',
      enableTranslation: './src/content-scripts/enable-translation.ts',
      disableTranslation: './src/content-scripts/disable-translation.ts',
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
      static: {
        directory: path.resolve(__dirname, './build'),
      },
    },
    performance: {
      maxAssetSize: 1000000,
      maxEntrypointSize: 1000000,
    },

    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|ts)x?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                cacheDirectory: true,
                presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
                plugins: ['react-native-web'],
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      alias,
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js'],
    },

    plugins: [
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [{ from: 'public', to: '.' }],
      }),
    ],
  };
};
```

Unfortunately, now, despite my best efforts, when I try to import the modules from the shared library, I get a long build error that I'm not sure how to interpret

```
ERROR in ../../node_modules/@react-native/assets/registry.js 13:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 'use strict';
| 
> export type PackagerAsset = {
|   +__packager_asset: boolean,
|   +fileSystemLocation: string,
 @ ../../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/AssetRegistry.js 13:0-57
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-asset/build/Asset.js 2:0-74 118:21-33
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-asset/build/index.js 2:0-24 2:0-24
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-av/build/AV.js 1:0-35 94:16-32 96:31-36
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-av/build/Audio.js 6:0-46 6:0-46
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-av/build/index.js 1:0-33 2:0-17
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/audio/AudioButton.tsx
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/WordView.tsx 1:319-350
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/index.tsx 1:281-302
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/index.ts 1:2116-2145
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/profile/CurrentUser.tsx 1:611-641
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/Popup.tsx 1:1446-1478
 @ ./src/popup/App.tsx 1:1139-1169
 @ ./src/popup/index.tsx 1:231-247

ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-native-table-component/components/cell.js 17:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (17:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|       data
|     ) : (
>       <Text style={[textStyle, styles.text]} {...props}>
|         {data}
|       </Text>
 @ ../../node_modules/react-native-table-component/index.js 4:0-41 4:0-41
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/swedish/SwedishNounView.tsx 1:347-386
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/swedish/SwedishWordView.tsx 1:234-262
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/WordView.tsx 1:548-584
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/index.tsx 1:281-302
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/index.ts 1:2116-2145
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/profile/CurrentUser.tsx 1:611-641
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/Popup.tsx 1:1446-1478
 @ ./src/popup/App.tsx 1:1139-1169
 @ ./src/popup/index.tsx 1:231-247

ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-native-table-component/components/cols.js 18:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|     return data ? (
>       <View style={[width ? { width: width } : { flex: 1 }, flex && { flex: flex }, style]}>
|         {data.map((item, i) => {
|           const height = heightArr && heightArr[i];
 @ ../../node_modules/react-native-table-component/index.js 2:0-46 2:0-46 2:0-46
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/swedish/SwedishNounView.tsx 1:347-386
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/swedish/SwedishWordView.tsx 1:234-262
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/WordView.tsx 1:548-584
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/index.tsx 1:281-302
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/index.ts 1:2116-2145
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/profile/CurrentUser.tsx 1:611-641
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/Popup.tsx 1:1446-1478
 @ ./src/popup/App.tsx 1:1139-1169
 @ ./src/popup/index.tsx 1:231-247

ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-native-table-component/components/rows.js 18:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|     return data ? (
>       <View style={[height && { height }, width && { width }, styles.row, style]}>
|         {data.map((item, i) => {
|           const flex = flexArr && flexArr[i];
 @ ../../node_modules/react-native-table-component/index.js 1:0-46 1:0-46 1:0-46
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/swedish/SwedishNounView.tsx 1:347-386
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/swedish/SwedishWordView.tsx 1:234-262
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/WordView.tsx 1:548-584
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/index.tsx 1:281-302
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/index.ts 1:2116-2145
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/profile/CurrentUser.tsx 1:611-641
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/Popup.tsx 1:1446-1478
 @ ./src/popup/App.tsx 1:1139-1169
 @ ./src/popup/index.tsx 1:231-247

ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-native-table-component/components/table.js 27:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (27:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|     return (
>       <View
|         style={[
|           this.props.style,
 @ ../../node_modules/react-native-table-component/index.js 3:0-57 3:0-57 3:0-57
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/swedish/SwedishNounView.tsx 1:347-386
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/swedish/SwedishWordView.tsx 1:234-262
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/WordView.tsx 1:548-584
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/index.tsx 1:281-302
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/index.ts 1:2116-2145
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/profile/CurrentUser.tsx 1:611-641
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/Popup.tsx 1:1446-1478
 @ ./src/popup/App.tsx 1:1139-1169
 @ ./src/popup/index.tsx 1:231-247

ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/AssetSourceResolver.js 13:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 'use strict';
| 
> export type ResolvedAssetSource = {|
|   +__packager_asset: boolean,
|   +width: ?number,
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-asset/build/AssetSourceResolver.js 1:0-83 2:15-34 3:0-65 3:0-65
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-asset/build/AssetSources.js 5:0-56 22:18-47
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-asset/build/Asset.js 3:0-51 155:30-47
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-asset/build/index.js 2:0-24 2:0-24
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-av/build/AV.js 1:0-35 94:16-32 96:31-36
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-av/build/Audio.js 6:0-46 6:0-46
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-av/build/index.js 1:0-33 2:0-17
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/audio/AudioButton.tsx
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/WordView.tsx 1:319-350
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/index.tsx 1:281-302
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/index.ts 1:2116-2145
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/profile/CurrentUser.tsx 1:611-641
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/Popup.tsx 1:1446-1478
 @ ./src/popup/App.tsx 1:1139-1169
 @ ./src/popup/index.tsx 1:231-247

ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/resolveAssetSource.js 15:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (15:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 'use strict';
| 
> import type {ResolvedAssetSource} from './AssetSourceResolver';
| 
| const AssetSourceResolver = require('./AssetSourceResolver');
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-asset/build/resolveAssetSource.js 1:0-81 2:15-33 3:0-64 3:0-64
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-asset/build/Asset.fx.js 3:0-66 6:4-30
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-asset/build/index.js 1:0-20
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-av/build/AV.js 1:0-35 94:16-32 96:31-36
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-av/build/Audio.js 6:0-46 6:0-46
 @ ../../node_modules/expo-av/build/index.js 1:0-33 2:0-17
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/audio/AudioButton.tsx
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/WordView.tsx 1:319-350
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/words/index.tsx 1:281-302
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/index.ts 1:2116-2145
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/profile/CurrentUser.tsx 1:611-641
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/Popup.tsx 1:1446-1478
 @ ./src/popup/App.tsx 1:1139-1169
 @ ./src/popup/index.tsx 1:231-247

ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent.js 13:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| // TODO: move this file to shims/ReactNative (requires React update and sync)
| 
> import type {HostComponent} from '../../Libraries/Renderer/shims/ReactNativeTypes';
| 
| import requireNativeComponent from '../../Libraries/ReactNative/requireNativeComponent';
 @ ../../node_modules/react-native-svg/lib/module/fabric/RectNativeComponent.js 1:0-93 2:15-37
 @ ../../node_modules/react-native-svg/lib/module/elements/Rect.js 5:0-54 34:44-53
 @ ../../node_modules/react-native-svg/lib/module/ReactNativeSVG.js 2:0-35 31:0-676
 @ ../../node_modules/react-native-svg/lib/module/index.js 1:0-33 1:0-33 2:0-43 2:0-43
 @ ../../node_modules/@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome/dist/converter.js
 @ ../../node_modules/@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome/dist/components/FontAwesomeIcon.js 11:40-63
 @ ../../node_modules/@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome/index.js 1:0-78 1:0-78
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/AsyncButton.tsx 1:731-779
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/index.ts 1:662-697
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/profile/CurrentUser.tsx 1:611-641
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/Popup.tsx 1:1446-1478
 @ ./src/popup/App.tsx 1:1139-1169
 @ ./src/popup/index.tsx 1:231-247

ERROR in ../../node_modules/react-native/index.js 14:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| // Components
> import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
| import typeof ActivityIndicator from './Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator';
| import typeof Button from './Libraries/Components/Button';
 @ ../../node_modules/@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome/dist/components/FontAwesomeIcon.js 15:19-42
 @ ../../node_modules/@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome/index.js 1:0-78 1:0-78
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/components/AsyncButton.tsx 1:731-779
 @ ../../packages/react-commons/src/index.ts 1:662-697
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/profile/CurrentUser.tsx 1:611-641
 @ ./src/popup/views/Popup/Popup.tsx 1:1446-1478
 @ ./src/popup/App.tsx 1:1139-1169
 @ ./src/popup/index.tsx 1:231-247
```

The errors appear to mostly come from the dependencies of my shared library (@fortawesome, expo-av, react-native-svg). Quite ironically, before I introduced these dependencies and only used react and react-native as my `peerDependency`, that kinda worked. After adding these, my expo project still builds just fine, no matter I use it to build the website or an android app (uses metro under the hood), but the chrome extension that uses webpack appears to have some major issues.

Comment: Did you ever get to a resolution for this problem?